# Generating heatmap from frames

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I have an issue as follow, i have coordinates x, y, z and r. Each of point is a Frame. Based on Frames want to generate heat-map with python. What i did till now, i imported the following frames:

```
-1.52588e-05  -1.52588e-05  8.17212e-06 300
-220.414  -220.305  217.847  79.5859
-220.899 220.54 -219.881 79.1004
219.275 218.495 -221.124 78.8756
-216.911 220.674 218.582 78.848
218.126 -219.362 221.977 78.0233
-222.961 -224.281 -204.107 75.7191
225.267 222.614 221.81 74.7329
```

parse it as well. From here i know is actually nothing really. 
as far as i'm concerned, generating heat-map based on frames. 
I don't know how should i do after importing frames.I'm really lost in context. 
Could someone give tips or way of doing i.e steps...
thanks
the code below is not work as well

```
import csv
import seaborn as sns

result = [[]]

with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        result.append(row)

        print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('  ', ' ')
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I getting alway error (tokenizing data) with your code,

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bam.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', header=None)
3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2048, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2130, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 2, saw 7

Comment: Please post your `data.txt` file content

Comment: Please post it in question because in comment it is one-line string. Line breaks are important

Comment: i am getting an error with your code, as follow TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Sorry. Have no idea. Works fine for me.